# Simple responsive 100% img attribute issue with iPad / iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

I have a really simple portfolio site (sample page: http://stevebishop.org/images/a_working_title/index.html) and I've made a responsive design that loads a 'mobile' style sheet that loads instead for the iPhone sized screen.

The only css really in the code for either is on regular style sheet the images are scaled 100% height of the screen and for the mobile they are 100% width. The intention being to have the largest possible image for each device with an image fitting on the screen all at once.

This all works fine, except the problem is with viewing on iPads - as they *should* act like desktops and load the regular css file but they don't seem to be able to handle the height: 100% attribute and instead display each image as very very big.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to change the code to something more stable, or to work a way around loading the 'mobile' css file for the iPad without it interfering with small desktops which I think it would.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `width: 100%`, you can use the properties for example `max-width: 400px` and `max-height:200px` to prevent the image is very large.

Hope that helps some.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, and it does limit the images going too big but because the images aren't all the same orientation and size then it causes some to become squished and not stick to their proportions. I'm using this: .resize {height: 100%; width:auto; max-height:900px; max-width:auto;} but this doesn't seem to retain the proportions correctly either. (900% is the biggest the images should be in height, with the width adjusting accordingly.